# MongoDB - $text operator search for phrase OR word(s)

Tags: mongodb, search

I'm doing a full text search that requires phrase(s) **OR** word(s).

As per the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/):

> If the $search string includes a phrase and individual terms, text search will only match the documents that include the phrase. More specifically, the search performs a logical AND of the phrase with the individual terms in the search string.
>
> For example, passed a $search string:

```
"\"ssl certificate\" authority key"
```

> The $text operator searches for the phrase "ssl certificate" **and** ("authority" or "key" or "ssl" or "certificate" ).

Is it possible to do this natively via MongoDB? Only other way I see now is to use Elastic search on top.

Update - the following search does not work and will cause a `BadValue Too many text expressions` error:

```
{
    $or: [{
        $text: {
            $search: "\"ssl certificate\""
        }
    }, {
        $text: {
            $search: "authority key"
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this natively is by performing multiple queries - one for each phrase and one for all stand-alone words together - and then merge the results on the application layer.

When relevance ranking is important for your use-case, [have mongodb also give you the text score](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-operator-text-score) and make use of it when merging your results.