# MongoDB $text search with higher weight score given to exact phrase matches

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking for a way to do a [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) search in MongoDB where matches to a multi-word phrase get assigned a higher score, but results still include matches to the individual terms with those receiving a lower score.

The docs give an example of the following search:

```
"\"ssl certificate\" authority key"
```

Meaning: The **$text** operator searches for the phrase **"ssl certificate" and ("authority" or "key" or "ssl" or "certificate" )**.

The use case I am seeking is closer to an **OR** rather than an **AND**, but without additional terms, similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160599/mongodb-text-operator-search-for-phrase-or-words).

```
"\"ssl certificate\" ssl certificate"
```

Where the desired logical meaning is: "ssl certificate" exactly is scored as more important, but matches to "ssl" or "certificate" are also included, scored as less important.

Given that the answer to the referenced post was that you need to execute multiple queries, it seems like that is the route I need to take: merging the results of text searches for **"ssl certificate"** and **ssl certificate** in the application layer.

It seems like a common enough use case, however, that I was curious if I was missing an alternative solution. Perhaps structuring the search string differently, applying the index weighting differently, using the aggregation pipleline, or ... ?