# MongoDB text search, exact phrase and logical operators

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to be able to search for text in a  collection(with its proper indexed field).

I'm my case I want to find exact phrases, for example using:

```
db[collection].find( {"$text": { "$search": "\"has five doors\""}})
```

When I would like to perform an AND match I use:

```
db[collection].find( {"$text": { "$search": " \"has five doors\" \"has an engine\" "}})
```

(This returns all the docs that has both exact phrases)

***But now, how I can do the same with an OR operation? I need all the docs that has either one of the second exact phrase(or both).***

I hope someone can think on an effective solution, since
Mongo does not allow to use the $or operator for more than one $text.

Regards.

Comment: Although a bit old, the answers here are still valid and suggest you to use separate queries
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160599
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160505

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! mmm, what do you think about generating an auxiliar collection with an aggregate pipeline that would merge all the separate results? (thinking on performance or good practices)